# How can I determine paragraph and line indents in MS Word documents with c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

Any one Please tell me is there any way to determine indents of each line and paragraph in MS word documents.
I’m new in Office programming and I intend to write an application which convert documents to text while they keeps their styles with converting intents to white-spaces.

Comment: Hey... have you got the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to WordML, it's a XML file which contains a doc document.
It's quite easy to generate and edit one. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212812%28v=office.11%29.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Comment: Actually, I want pars documents which been produced by Word and as you know word generates so complicate XML file. Is there any SDK,APIs or something like that for manipulate easily word documents.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look to Microsoft.Interop library.

Answer (score 0):

The xml in .docx files is complicated but you can ignore most of it (especially if reading it via the C# library). Unzip the docx and look in word/document.xml. The indent is specified in the paragraph properties (w:pPr). eg this is the xml for a paragraph indented by 540 somethings (about one tab's width, not sure what the units are):

```
<w:p w:rsidR="009932EC" w:rsidRDefault="009932EC" w:rsidP="000A0336">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:left="540" />
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Indented.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.indentation.aspx